# Getting the language used by Siri

Tags: ios, sirikit

How is it possible to know which language is used by Siri, in the extension and in the host app?

As the user has the ability to choose a different language for Siri, it can't be assumed that it is the same as the host app one. It's relevant to know it in the extension if some processing is required, and in the app to set up a custom vocabulary that could make sense (the run-time defined one).

Using `Locale.current` in the extension returns the Locale of the host app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a function in SiriKit, but I didn't search in the right classes: `+[INPreferences siriLanguageCode]`